# A complex Entity Framework / AutoMapper REST case

Tags: entity-framework, rest, automapper

I am assigned the implementation of a REST GET with a complex DB model and somewhat complex output layout. Although I am a REST beginner, I have lost "rest" on this for 2 weeks spinning my wheels, and Google was of no help as well.

Here's a simplification of the existing DB I am given to work with:

```
Table group : {
  Column id Guid
  Column name string
  Primary key: {id}
}
Table account
{
  Column id Guid
  Column name string
  Primary key: {id}
}
Table groupGroupMembership
{
  Column parentGroupId Guid
  Column childGroupId Guid
  Primary key: {parentGroupId, childGroupId}
}
Table accountGroupMembership
{
  Column parentGroupId Guid
  Column childAccountId Guid
  Primary key: {parentGroupId, childAccountId}
}
```

So clearly you guessed it: There is a many-to-many relationship between parent a child groups. Hence a group can have many parent and child groups. Similarly, an account can have many parent groups.

The DB model I came up with in C# (in namespace DBAccess.Models.Tables):

```
public class Group
{
  // properties
  public Guid id { get; set; }
  public string? name { get; set; }

  // navigation properties
  public List<GroupMemberAccount>? childAccounts { get; set; }
  public List<GroupMemberGroup>? childGroups { get; set; }
  public List<GroupMemberGroup>? parentGroups { get; set; }  
}
public class Account
{
  // properties
  public Guid id { get; set; }
  public string? name { get; set; }

  // navigation properties
  public List<GroupMemberAccount>? parentGroups { get; set; }  
}

public class GroupMemberAccount
{
    // properties
    public Guid parentGroupId { get; set; }
    public Guid childAccountId { get; set; }

    //navigation properties
    public Group? parentGroup { get; set; }
    public Account? childAccount { get; set; }

    static internal void OnModelCreating( EntityTypeBuilder<GroupMemberAccount> modelBuilder )
    {
      modelBuilder.HasKey(gma => new { gma.parentGroupId, gma.childAccountId });
      modelBuilder
          .HasOne(gma => gma.parentGroup)
          .WithMany(g => g.childAccounts)
          .HasForeignKey(gma => gma.parentGroupId);
      modelBuilder
          .HasOne(gma => gma.childAccount)
          .WithMany(a => a.parentGroups)
          .HasForeignKey(gma => gma.childAccountId);
    }
}

public class GroupMemberGroup
{
    // properties
    public Guid parentGroupId { get; set; }
    public Guid childGroupId { get; set; }

    //navigation properties
    public Group? parentGroup { get; set; }
    public Group? childGroup { get; set; }

    static internal void OnModelCreating(EntityTypeBuilder<GroupMemberGroup> modelBuilder)
    {
      modelBuilder.HasKey(gmg => new { gmg.parentGroupId, gmg.childGroupId });
      modelBuilder
          .HasOne(gmg => gmg.parentGroup)
          .WithMany(g => g.childGroups)
          .HasForeignKey(gmg => gmg.parentGroupId);
      modelBuilder
          .HasOne(gmg => gmg.childGroup)
          .WithMany(g => g.parentGroups)
          .HasForeignKey(gmg => gmg.childGroupId);
    }
}
```

The corresponding DTO model I created:

```
public class Account
{
  public Guid id { get; set; }
  public string? name { get; set; }
  public List<GroupMemberAccount>? parentGroups { get; set; }
}
public class AccountMappingProfile : AutoMapper.Profile
{
  public AccountMappingProfile()
  {
    CreateMap<DBAccess.Models.Tables.Account, Account>();
  }
}

public class Group
{
    public Guid id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }

    public GroupChildren children { get; set; } = null!;
};
public class GroupChildren 
{
  public List<GroupMemberAccount>? childAccounts { get; set; } = null!;
  public List<GroupMemberGroup>? childGroups { get; set; } = null!;
}
public class GroupMemberAccount
{
  public Guid parentGroupId { get; set; }
  public Guid childAccountId { get; set; }

  //public Group? parentgroup { get; set; } // commented out because no need to output in a GET request
  public Account? childAccount { get; set; }
}
public class GroupMemberGroup
{
  public Guid parentGroupid { get; set; }
  public Guid childGroupId { get; set; }

  //public Group? parentGroup { get; set; }; // commented out because no need to output in a GET request
  public Group? childGroup { get; set; };
}
```

What you need to spot here is the difference in classes Group between the DB and DTO models.
In the DB model, Group has 3 lists: childAccounts, childGroups and parentGroups.
In the DTO model, Group has 1 node children of type GroupChildren which is a class that contains 2 of those 3 lists.
Hence an additional difficulty when it comes to design the mapping. That difference is intentional because it matches the following desired output for an endpoint such as: GET .../api/rest/group({some group guid}) is something like:

```
{
  "id": "some group guid",
  "name": "some group name",
  "children": {
    "childAccounts":{
      "account":{ "name": "some account name 1"}
      "account":{ "name": "some account name 2"}
      ...
    }
    "childFroups":{
      "group":{ "name": "some group name 1"}
      "group":{ "name": "some group name 2"}
      ...
    }
  },
}
```

obtained from following typical controller code:

```
[HttpGet("Groups({key})")]
[ApiConventionMethod(typeof(ApiConventions),
                     nameof(ApiConventions.GetWithKey))]
public async Task<ActionResult<Group>> Get(Guid key, ODataQueryOptions<Group> options)
{
    var g = await (await context.Group.Include(g => g.childAccounts)
                                      .Include(g => g.childGroups)
                                      .Where(g => g.id == key)
                                      .GetQueryAsync(mapper, options)   // note the mapper here is the mapping defined below
                  ).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    if (g is null)
    {
        return ResourceNotFound();
    }
    return Ok(g);
}
```

So here's the missing part to all this. Unless there are major errors in all of the above, I have a very strong intuition that it is the mapping that is failing to get me the requested output above.

```
public class GroupMappingProfile : AutoMapper.Profile
{
  public GroupMappingProfile()
  {
    // the rather straightforward.
    CreateMap<DBAccess.Models.Tables.GroupMemberAccount, GroupMemberAccount>();
    CreateMap<DBAccess.Models.Tables.GroupMemberGroup, GroupMemberGroup>();

    //Attempt 1: the not so straightforward. An explicit exhaustive mapping of everything, down to every single primitive type
    CreateMap<DBAccess.Models.Tables.Group, Group>()
      .ForMember(g => g.children, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => new GroupMembers
        {
          childAccounts = src.childAccounts!.Select(x => new GroupMemberAccount { parentGroupId = x.parentGroupId, 
                                                                                  childAccountId = x.childAccountId,
                                                                                  childAccount = new Account { id = x.childAccount!.id, 
                                                                                                               name = x.childAccount!.name
                                                                                                             }
                                                                               }
                                                   ).ToList(),

          //childGroups = src.childGroups!.Select(x => new GroupMemberGroup(x)).ToList(),

          childGroups = src.childGroups!.Select(x => new GroupMemberGroup { parentGroupId = x.parentGroupId, 
                                                                            childGroupId = x.childGroupId,
                                                                            childGroup = new Group { id = x.childGroup!.id, 
                                                                                                     name = x.childGroup!.name
                                                                                                   }
                                                                          }
                                                  ).ToList(),
        }));

    //Attempt 2: mapper injection
    IMapper mapper = null!;
    CreateMap<DBAccess.Models.Tables.Group, Group>()
      .BeforeMap((_, _, context) => mapper = (IMapper)context.Items["mapper"])  //ADDING THIS LINE CAUSES ALL QUERIES TO LOOK FOR A NON EXISTENT Group.Groupid column 
      .ForMember(g => g.children, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => new GroupMembers
      {
          childAccounts = mapper.Map<List<DBAccess.Models.Tables.GroupMemberAccount>, List<GroupMemberAccount>>(src.childAccounts!),
          childGroups  = mapper.Map<List<DBAccess.Models.Tables.GroupMemberGroup>, List<GroupMemberGroup>>(src.childGroups!)
      }))
  }
}
```

Attempt1 will yield:

```
{
    "id": "some guid",
    "name": "some name"
    "children": {}
}
```

even though the generated SQL does fetch all the required data to fill "children"

Attempt2 (mapper injection) is a technique I was suggested and have no clue how it is supposed to work. From what I gather, the mapping functions creates a few maps for some basic types while it uses its "future" self to create the remaining mappings, whenever it will be invoked in the future. Looks somehow like a one-time recursion.
However, it crashes as the generated SQL will look for a non-existent view column group.Groupid

```
SELECT [t].[id], [t].[name], 
       [g0].[parentGroupId], [g0].[childAccountId], 
       [g1].[parentGroupId], [g1].[childGroupId], [g1].[Groupid]    -- where does [g1].[Groupid] come from??
FROM (
    SELECT TOP(1) [g].[id], [g].[name]
    FROM [HID_Rest].[group] AS [g]
    WHERE [g].[id] = @__key_0
) AS [t]
LEFT JOIN [HID_Rest].[groupMemberAccount] AS [g0] ON [t].[id] = [g0].[parentGroupId]
LEFT JOIN [HID_Rest].[groupMemberGroup]   AS [g1] ON [t].[id] = [g1].[parentGroupId]
ORDER BY ...
```

So regardless of the mapping profile I experimented with, what is the right mapping profile I need (and what ever else) to get the expected JSON output above? Or is this desired JSON structure possible at all?

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html

Answer (score 0):

After further work, I have figured that there was nothing wrong with my models and mapping. There's still something wrong though as the output to my GET requests is still incomplete. Here's the current new issue I need to deal with to solve this problem:

[Issue with REST controller function Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase.OK()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72607321/issue-with-rest-controller-function-microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-controllerbase-ok)